# app crashes when I change the time on a date picker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uidatepicker, crash

I made an app with a textview that when you tap it, a date picker comes up. Is it something wrong with my code?

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(112, 88, 97, 30)];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:textField];

UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[textField setInputView:datePicker];
```

I am getting the error `2013-08-04 20:38:54.249 Habit Pal[7252:c07] -[SleepModeViewController datePickerValueChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8840d70`

Comment: hi just implement -(void)datePickerValueChanged:(UIDatePicker)datePicker{
//Put what you want to occur whan the value changes

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a "`datePickerValueChanged:`" method to your SleepMoveViewController.h & .m file.

If you don't have one, then you should create one.

And if you have one, check to make certain it's the right API signature.  For example:

```
- (void) datePickerValueChanged: (id) sender;
```

Comment: Really new to programming, so how do I make a `datePickerValueDidChange`? Do I just add `- (void) datePickerValueChanged: (id) sender;` anywhere? And do I need to put this code under it?

Answer (score 0):

As you know you dont have a value for `-(void)datePickerValueChanged`, You can put this anywhere below in the file.

Basically you would create something like this:

```
-(void)datePickerValueChanged:(id)sender{
//Put what you want to occur whan the value changes

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this method in your `SleepModeViewController`

```
-(void) datePickerValueChanged:(UIDatePicker*) datePicker {
//write your code here
}
```